# SQL query UPDATE multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this query?

```
UPDATE user166x136
SET desc = CASE id
WHEN 18 THEN 'apple' WHEN 14 THEN 'banana' WHEN 21 THEN 'pear' WHEN 17 THEN 'orange' WHEN 19 THEN 'lemon' 
          END
WHERE id IN (18,14,21,17,19)
```

`id` is `INT`
`desc` is `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). If you're going to use it you must wrap it in ticks.

```
SET `desc` = CASE id
```

You're also missing a quote before `orange`

```
WHEN 17 THEN orange'
           ^^^^
           HERE
```

It should be

```
WHEN 17 THEN 'orange'
```

And lastly, as pointed out by Minh, you're missing the `CASE` in `END CASE`

```
END CASE
```

So you have a hat trick of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing `END CASE` keyword

```
UPDATE user166x136
SET `desc` = CASE id
            WHEN 18 THEN 'apple'
            WHEN 14 THEN 'banana'
            WHEN 21 THEN 'pear'
            WHEN 17 THEN 'orange'
            WHEN 19 THEN 'lemon' 
          END CASE
WHERE id IN (18,14,21,17,19)
```